# fourier series sketching (by hand)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I calculated the Fourier Series representation of $f (x) = 1 − |x|$ on $−1 ≤ x ≤ 1$ and now I am asked to sketch the graph of the series on $−3 ≤ x ≤ 3$ by hand. How do I do this? I read through my lecture notes and find it very confusing. In my notes, all the axis of graphs are using $x$ over $\pi$ or $y$ over $\pi$, is that always the case when I come across with rage involving $\pi$?

Comment: Are you supposed to be taking an extension of some kind (odd or even)?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the series is the periodic extension (of period $2$) of $f$. All you have to do is copy the graph of $f$ on $[-1,1]$ on $[1,3]$ and $[-3,-1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please further explain your answer, how can I know the series is the periodic extension?

Comment: Because $\sin(n\pi x)$ and $\cos(n\pi x)$ are periodic of period $2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Indeed I am not quite sure what do I need to sketch. Do I need to sketch the furious series that I calculated? or just the f(x) given. In addition, for the axis, do I simply use x and y or i need to modify them into x over pi and y over pi? Many thanks

Comment: The sum of the series is exactly $f$ on $[-1,1]$, and its periodic extension on the rest of $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: In general speaking, does the curve has to be continuous?

Comment: In this particular case it is, because $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and $f(-1)=f(1)$.